# How to replace text in a column after filter

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

After I apply a filter in A1 I get a result like:

```
A      B      C      D 

Uno    1      3      1
Uno    1      2      2
Tres   2      2      3
```

I want to replace "Uno" for "Dos" in the same cells.

```
A      B      C      D 

Dos    1      3      1
Dos    1      2      2
Tres   2      2      3
```

I have seen `SUBSTITUTE()` and `REPLACE()` functions, but, they put the replacement in another cells.

I have tried:

```
A1: SUBSTITUTE(A1:A)
```

Comment: can you share that filter formula?

Comment: This is the filter formula applied on A1:  =IFERROR(filter(K:N,L:L="ok"), " ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(IFERROR(FILTER(K:N, L:L="ok"), " "), "Uno", "Dos"))
```

- `REGEXREPLACE(range, "replace this", "to this")`
- `ARRAYFORMULA` - for continuity

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(IFERROR(FILTER(K:N, L:L="ok"), " "), 
 "Uno", "Dos"), "Tres", "Cuatro")
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly, what about If I want to change more than one word? "Uno" for "Dos" AND "Tres" for "Cuatro"??